# Organize the file by AWK

Tags: bash, file, unix, awk

Well, I have the following file:

```
week  ID      Father  Mother  Group  C_Id    Weight  Age  System  Gender
9     107001  728     7110    922    107001  1287    56   2       2
10    107001  728     7110    1022   107001  1319    63   2       2
11    107001  728     7110    1122   107001  1491    70   2       2
1     107002  702     7006    111    107002  43      1    1       1
2     107002  702     7006    211    107002  103     7    1       1
4     107002  702     7006    411    107002  372     21   1       1
1     107003  729     7112    111    107003  40      1    1       1
2     107003  729     7112    211    107003  90      7    1       1
5     107003  729     7112    511    107003  567     28   1       1
7     107003  729     7112    711    107003  1036    42   1       1
```

I need to transpose the Age ($8) and Weight ($7) columns, where the column ($8) will be the new label (1, 7, 21, 28, 42, 56, 63, 70). Additionally, the age label should be in ascending order. But not all animals have all age measures, animals that do not possess should be given the "NS" symbol. The Id, Father, Mother, System, and Gender columns will be maintained, but with the transposition of the Age and Weight columns, it will not be necessary to repeat these variables as in the first table. Week, Group and C_Id columns are not required. Visually, I need that file be this way:

```
ID  Father  Mother  System  Gender   1  7   21  28  42   56   63   70
107001  728   7110     2        2    NS NS  NS  NS  NS   1287 1319 1491
107002  702   7006     1        1    43 103 372 NS  NS   NS   NS   NS
107003  729   7112     1        1    40 90  NS  567 1036 NS   NS   NS
```

I tried this program:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NR==1{h=$2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $9 OFS $10; next}
            {a[$2]=(($1 in a)?(a[$1] OFS $NF):(OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $9 OFS $10));
             if(!($8 in b)) {h=h OFS $8; b[$8]}}
        END{print h; for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' banco.txt | column -t > a
```

But I got it:

```
ID  Father  Mother  System  Gender
  56  63  70  1  7  21  28  42
107001  728   7110     2        2
107002  702   7006     1        1
107003  729   7112     1        1
```

And I'm stuck at that point, any suggestion please? Thanks.

Comment: I hope I have made it easier to understand. I'm sorry, but I'm not native in the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for "sorted_in":

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    id = $2
    weight = $7
    age = $8

    idAge2weight[id,age] = weight
    id2common[id] = $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $9 OFS $10
    ages[age]
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    printf "%s", id2common["ID"]
    for (age in ages) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, age
    }
    print ""
    delete id2common["ID"]

    for (id in id2common) {
        printf "%s", id2common[id]
        for (age in ages) {
            weight = ((id,age) in idAge2weight ? idAge2weight[id,age] : "NS")
            printf "%s%s", OFS, weight
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
ID      Father  Mother  System  Gender  Age  1   7    21   28   42    56    63    70
107001  728     7110    2       2       NS   NS  NS   NS   NS   NS    1287  1319  1491
107002  702     7006    1       1       NS   43  103  372  NS   NS    NS    NS    NS
107003  729     7112    1       1       NS   40  90   NS   567  1036  NS    NS    NS
```

I added the pipe to `column -t` just so you could see the field alignment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it did not work. The following message appears: a- ages[age]: command not found; b - syntax error near unexpected token ('; c - for (age in ages) {' ; and I could not solve

Comment: Please, I did not quite understand what I did wrong! And I did not understand this command: `cat tst.awk`. How should I proceed? Thanks again for your attention and especially patience!

Comment: The `cat` I knew, I was in doubt about this tst.awk file. Although very obvious, I reasoned in a different way, very wrong. I've been really dumb, I'm ashamed. Anyway, it worked perfectly, I appreciate your attention and sorry for the mental slowness.